# In iOS 10, how to allows videos to rotate in landscape when displayed in a portrait only iOS app

Tags: ios, ios10

before iOS 10, there is two notification 
***MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification*** and ***MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification***   to observer enter full screen mode, but in iOS 10 the notification is deprecated, so how to change the  *UIInterfaceOrientationMask* when device rotate?

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
         isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {

        if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
             isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

            // look for it inside UINavigationController
            UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];

            // is at the top?
            if ([nc.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

                // or it's presented from the top?
            } else if ([[nc.topViewController presentedViewController]
                        isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
            }
        }
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After search I found that the pop media player is AVFullScreenViewController, so below snippet can resolve this problem, but is iOS 10, when exit full screen, the status bar is miss.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    id presentedViewController = [window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
    NSString *className = presentedViewController ? NSStringFromClass([presentedViewController class]) : nil;


    if (window && ([className isEqualToString:@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController"] || [className isEqualToString:@"AVFullScreenViewController"])) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dklt  when exit full screen, you must change statusbar status.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a working solution in Swift. This function goes in the AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    if let presentedViewController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        let className = String(describing: type(of: presentedViewController))
        if ["MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController", "MPMoviePlayerViewController", "AVFullScreenViewController"].contains(className)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
        }
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```